# Using theme hook, how do I get block contents into the $comm line?

Tags: blocks, hooks

```
if ( isset($vars['content']['#block_content']) ) { // check for custom content
    if ($vars['content']['#block_content']->type[0]->getValue()['target_id'] == 'js_file_block') { // only run on js_file_block types
      $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block-content');
      $comm = current($storage->loadByProperties(['type' => 'block']));
      $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
      $vars['inlinejs2'] = array();
      if ($comm !== false) {
        foreach ($comm->get('field_js_url') as $script_block) {
          $vars['inlinejs2'][] = $script_block->value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong, but it will not make the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access the entity in a template preprocess hook, there is a much simpler way:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(array &$variables) {
  // check for custom content block
  if ($variables['base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
    // the entity is alreary availale in the preprocess hook, no need for another query
    $blockContentEntity = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
    // my advice: pass the entire entity to the template, so you can access all the block fields
    // in Twig without further preprocessing, similar to node templates, e.g.
    // {{ block_content.field_whatever.0.value }}
    $vars['block_content'] = $blockContentEntity;
    // further processsing only for custom content blocks of type 'js_file_block'
    if ($blockContentEntity && $blockContentEntity->bundle() == 'js_file_block') {
        //...whatever you need in here...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis code works for me.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {  
    if ($content['#block_content']->bundle() == 'megamenu_image_video_block') {
      if(isset($content['#block_content']->get('field_select_campaign')->target_id) && !empty($content['#block_content']->get('field_select_campaign')->target_id)) {
        $selectedCampaign = node_load($content['#block_content']->get('field_select_campaign')->target_id);
        $variables['headerMegamenuCampaignTitle'] = $selectedCampaign->get('title')->value;
      }
    }
}
```